# How to reduce case in VB Net?

Tags: vb.net

Can this code be somewhat shorter? values change from 10 in 10 cases to +1, as follows as follows. For each textbox, I have these 80 cases, and I have a total of 30 textboxes and the code is too long. Once again I have to repeat the code, because aryText = TextNSt1.Text.Split ("," c) - up to aryText = TextNSt30.Text.Split ("," c) - so 30 times you code this, and I do not really like it, comma, the code is too long. The code changes with +1 in the following cases from Case 1 to 10, Cases 11-20, Cases 21-30, Cases 31-40, Cases 41-50, Cases 51-60, Cases 61-70, 71- 80...

```
Dim i As Integer
    Dim aryText() As String
    'SPLIT THE TEXT INTO AN ARRAY' 
    aryText = TextNSt2.Text.Split(","c)
    For i = 0 To UBound(aryText)
        Select Case aryText(i)
            Case "1"
                LbNxSt1.Text = Val(LbNxSt1.Text) + 1
                txtS10.Text = Val(txtS10.Text) + 1
                txtDrawB1.Text = Val(txtDrawB1.Text) + 1
            Case "2"
                LbNxSt2.Text = Val(LbNxSt2.Text) + 1
                txtS10.Text = Val(txtS10.Text) + 2
                txtDrawB1.Text = Val(txtDrawB1.Text) + 1
            Case "3"
                LbNxSt3.Text = Val(LbNxSt3.Text) + 1
                txtS10.Text = Val(txtS10.Text) + 3
                txtDrawB1.Text = Val(txtDrawB1.Text) + 1
            Case "4"
                LbNxSt4.Text = Val(LbNxSt4.Text) + 1
                txtS10.Text = Val(txtS10.Text) + 4
                txtDrawB1.Text = Val(txtDrawB1.Text) + 1
            Case "5"
                LbNxSt5.Text = Val(LbNxSt5.Text) + 1
                txtS10.Text = Val(txtS10.Text) + 5
                txtDrawB1.Text = Val(txtDrawB1.Text) + 1
            Case "6"
                LbNxSt6.Text = Val(LbNxSt6.Text) + 1
                txtS10.Text = Val(txtS10.Text) + 6
                txtDrawB1.Text = Val(txtDrawB1.Text) + 1
            Case "7"
                LbNxSt7.Text = Val(LbNxSt7.Text) + 1
                txtS10.Text = Val(txtS10.Text) + 7
                txtDrawB1.Text = Val(txtDrawB1.Text) + 1
            Case "8"
                LbNxSt8.Text = Val(LbNxSt8.Text) + 1
                txtS10.Text = Val(txtS10.Text) + 8
                txtDrawB1.Text = Val(txtDrawB1.Text) + 1
            Case "9"
                LbNxSt9.Text = Val(LbNxSt9.Text) + 1
                txtS10.Text = Val(txtS10.Text) + 9
                txtDrawB1.Text = Val(txtDrawB1.Text) + 1
            Case "10"
                LbNxSt10.Text = Val(LbNxSt10.Text) + 1
                txtS10.Text = Val(txtS10.Text) + 10
                txtDrawB1.Text = Val(txtDrawB1.Text) + 1
            Case "11"
                LbNxSt11.Text = Val(LbNxSt11.Text) + 1
                txtS20.Text = Val(txtS20.Text) + 1
                txtDrawB2.Text = Val(txtDrawB2.Text) + 1
            Case "12"
                LbNxSt12.Text = Val(LbNxSt12.Text) + 1
                txtS20.Text = Val(txtS20.Text) + 2
                txtDrawB2.Text = Val(txtDrawB2.Text) + 1
            Case "13"
                LbNxSt13.Text = Val(LbNxSt13.Text) + 1
                txtS20.Text = Val(txtS20.Text) + 3
                txtDrawB2.Text = Val(txtDrawB2.Text) + 1
            Case "14"
                LbNxSt14.Text = Val(LbNxSt14.Text) + 1
                txtS20.Text = Val(txtS20.Text) + 4
                txtDrawB2.Text = Val(txtDrawB2.Text) + 1
            Case "15"
                LbNxSt15.Text = Val(LbNxSt15.Text) + 1
                txtS20.Text = Val(txtS20.Text) + 5
                txtDrawB2.Text = Val(txtDrawB2.Text) + 1
            Case "16"
                LbNxSt16.Text = Val(LbNxSt16.Text) + 1
                txtS20.Text = Val(txtS20.Text) + 6
                txtDrawB2.Text = Val(txtDrawB2.Text) + 1
            Case "17"
                LbNxSt17.Text = Val(LbNxSt17.Text) + 1
                txtS20.Text = Val(txtS20.Text) + 7
                txtDrawB2.Text = Val(txtDrawB2.Text) + 1
            Case "18"
                LbNxSt18.Text = Val(LbNxSt18.Text) + 1
                txtS20.Text = Val(txtS20.Text) + 8
                txtDrawB2.Text = Val(txtDrawB2.Text) + 1
            Case "19"
                LbNxSt19.Text = Val(LbNxSt19.Text) + 1
                txtS20.Text = Val(txtS20.Text) + 9
                txtDrawB2.Text = Val(txtDrawB2.Text) + 1
            Case "20"
                LbNxSt20.Text = Val(LbNxSt20.Text) + 1
                txtS20.Text = Val(txtS20.Text) + 10
                txtDrawB2.Text = Val(txtDrawB2.Text) + 1
            Case "21"
                LbNxSt21.Text = Val(LbNxSt21.Text) + 1
                txtS30.Text = Val(txtS30.Text) + 1
                txtDrawB3.Text = Val(txtDrawB3.Text) + 1
            Case "22"
                LbNxSt22.Text = Val(LbNxSt22.Text) + 1
                txtS30.Text = Val(txtS30.Text) + 2
                txtDrawB3.Text = Val(txtDrawB3.Text) + 1
            Case "23"
                LbNxSt23.Text = Val(LbNxSt23.Text) + 1
                txtS30.Text = Val(txtS30.Text) + 3
                txtDrawB3.Text = Val(txtDrawB3.Text) + 1
            Case "24"
                LbNxSt24.Text = Val(LbNxSt24.Text) + 1
                txtS30.Text = Val(txtS30.Text) + 4
                txtDrawB3.Text = Val(txtDrawB3.Text) + 1
            Case "25"
                LbNxSt25.Text = Val(LbNxSt25.Text) + 1
                txtS30.Text = Val(txtS30.Text) + 5
                txtDrawB3.Text = Val(txtDrawB3.Text) + 1
            Case "26"
                LbNxSt26.Text = Val(LbNxSt26.Text) + 1
                txtS30.Text = Val(txtS30.Text) + 6
                txtDrawB3.Text = Val(txtDrawB3.Text) + 1
            Case "27"
                LbNxSt27.Text = Val(LbNxSt27.Text) + 1
                txtS30.Text = Val(txtS30.Text) + 7
                txtDrawB3.Text = Val(txtDrawB3.Text) + 1
            Case "28"
                LbNxSt28.Text = Val(LbNxSt28.Text) + 1
                txtS30.Text = Val(txtS30.Text) + 8
                txtDrawB3.Text = Val(txtDrawB3.Text) + 1
            Case "29"
                LbNxSt29.Text = Val(LbNxSt29.Text) + 1
                txtS30.Text = Val(txtS30.Text) + 9
                txtDrawB3.Text = Val(txtDrawB3.Text) + 1
            Case "30"
                LbNxSt30.Text = Val(LbNxSt30.Text) + 1
                txtS30.Text = Val(txtS30.Text) + 10
                txtDrawB3.Text = Val(txtDrawB3.Text) + 1
            Case "31"
                LbNxSt31.Text = Val(LbNxSt31.Text) + 1
                txtS40.Text = Val(txtS40.Text) + 1
                txtDrawB4.Text = Val(txtDrawB4.Text) + 1
            Case "32"
                LbNxSt32.Text = Val(LbNxSt32.Text) + 1
                txtS40.Text = Val(txtS40.Text) + 2
                txtDrawB4.Text = Val(txtDrawB4.Text) + 1
            Case "33"
                LbNxSt33.Text = Val(LbNxSt33.Text) + 1
                txtS40.Text = Val(txtS40.Text) + 3
                txtDrawB4.Text = Val(txtDrawB4.Text) + 1
            Case "34"
                LbNxSt34.Text = Val(LbNxSt34.Text) + 1
                txtS40.Text = Val(txtS40.Text) + 4
                txtDrawB4.Text = Val(txtDrawB4.Text) + 1
            Case "35"
                LbNxSt35.Text = Val(LbNxSt35.Text) + 1
                txtS40.Text = Val(txtS40.Text) + 5
                txtDrawB4.Text = Val(txtDrawB4.Text) + 1
            Case "36"
                LbNxSt36.Text = Val(LbNxSt36.Text) + 1
                txtS40.Text = Val(txtS40.Text) + 6
                txtDrawB4.Text = Val(txtDrawB4.Text) + 1
            Case "37"
                LbNxSt37.Text = Val(LbNxSt37.Text) + 1
                txtS40.Text = Val(txtS40.Text) + 7
                txtDrawB4.Text = Val(txtDrawB4.Text) + 1
            Case "38"
                LbNxSt38.Text = Val(LbNxSt38.Text) + 1
                txtS40.Text = Val(txtS40.Text) + 8
                txtDrawB4.Text = Val(txtDrawB4.Text) + 1
            Case "39"
                LbNxSt39.Text = Val(LbNxSt39.Text) + 1
                txtS40.Text = Val(txtS40.Text) + 9
                txtDrawB4.Text = Val(txtDrawB4.Text) + 1
            Case "40"
                LbNxSt40.Text = Val(LbNxSt40.Text) + 1
                txtS40.Text = Val(txtS40.Text) + 10
                txtDrawB4.Text = Val(txtDrawB4.Text) + 1
            Case "41"
                LbNxSt41.Text = Val(LbNxSt41.Text) + 1
                txtS50.Text = Val(txtS50.Text) + 1
                txtDrawB5.Text = Val(txtDrawB5.Text) + 1
            Case "42"
                LbNxSt42.Text = Val(LbNxSt42.Text) + 1
                txtS50.Text = Val(txtS50.Text) + 2
                txtDrawB5.Text = Val(txtDrawB5.Text) + 1
            Case "43"
                LbNxSt43.Text = Val(LbNxSt43.Text) + 1
                txtS50.Text = Val(txtS50.Text) + 3
                txtDrawB5.Text = Val(txtDrawB5.Text) + 1
            Case "44"
                LbNxSt44.Text = Val(LbNxSt44.Text) + 1
                txtS50.Text = Val(txtS50.Text) + 4
                txtDrawB5.Text = Val(txtDrawB5.Text) + 1
            Case "45"
                LbNxSt45.Text = Val(LbNxSt45.Text) + 1
                txtS50.Text = Val(txtS50.Text) + 5
                txtDrawB5.Text = Val(txtDrawB5.Text) + 1
            Case "46"
                LbNxSt46.Text = Val(LbNxSt46.Text) + 1
                txtS50.Text = Val(txtS50.Text) + 6
                txtDrawB5.Text = Val(txtDrawB5.Text) + 1
            Case "47"
                LbNxSt47.Text = Val(LbNxSt47.Text) + 1
                txtS50.Text = Val(txtS50.Text) + 7
                txtDrawB5.Text = Val(txtDrawB5.Text) + 1
            Case "48"
                LbNxSt48.Text = Val(LbNxSt48.Text) + 1
                txtS50.Text = Val(txtS50.Text) + 8
                txtDrawB5.Text = Val(txtDrawB5.Text) + 1
            Case "49"
                LbNxSt49.Text = Val(LbNxSt49.Text) + 1
                txtS50.Text = Val(txtS50.Text) + 9
                txtDrawB5.Text = Val(txtDrawB5.Text) + 1
            Case "50"
                LbNxSt50.Text = Val(LbNxSt50.Text) + 1
                txtS50.Text = Val(txtS50.Text) + 10
                txtDrawB5.Text = Val(txtDrawB5.Text) + 1
```

Comment: Have you tried reflection? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can work out the relationship between the "number" and the control, you can get the control like this:

```
For ary = 1 To 30
    Dim aryText = Me.Controls("TextNSt" & ary).Text.Split({","c})

    For i = 0 To aryText.Length - 1
        Dim s = aryText(i)

        Dim n = CInt(s)
        Dim LbNxStNum = n Mod 10
        If LbNxStNum = 0 Then LbNxStNum = 10
        Dim LbNxSt = Me.Controls("LbNxSt" & LbNxStNum)

        LbNxSt.Text = (CInt(LbNxSt.Text) + 1).ToString()

        Dim txtSNum = (Math.Floor(n / 10) + 1) * 10
        Dim txtS = Me.Controls("txtS" & txtSNum)

        txtS.Text = (CInt(txtS.Text) + LbNxStNum).ToString()

        Dim txtDrawBNum = Math.Ceiling(n / 10)
        Dim txtDrawB = Me.Controls("txtDrawB" & txtDrawBNum)

        txtDrawB.Text = (CInt(txtDrawB.Text) + 1).ToString()

    Next

Next
```

I may have off-by-one errors in there, so you may need to make adjustments.

If `Me` is not the container, change it to use the appropriate Panel/whatever container.

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly ! I left only the code with txtDraw, the rest I deleted because it was useless. For Ary 1-30 it also calculates all the existing amounts from Textbox, but I want to calculate only the amount of each textbox, not all, what we have already done because we have improved the code.

Comment: Solved, I did not know how to do it. I now Know... :D